# Excel - VBA - Add-In - Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I created an excel macro "add-in" for the first time. So now I can use the same macro across multiple workbooks using the quick link at the top of the workbook.

My issue is that the first command of my Macro is to add in a sheet "Sheet1". My workbook has 2 sheets in it currently. "Attrition 2017" and "Attrition 2018".

When I added in "Sheet1" the first time nothing happened, and the rest of my workbook errored out because of it. The second time I went through it said "Sheet1" already exists. This is the only workbook I have open. I tried it with numerous sheet names. it keeps adding sheets to an unknown spot then stating that they already exist. the rest of my code works with the add-in.

My code for adding in the worksheet works when not using the add-in function. here it is.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Sheet1"
    End With
```

Comment: I suspect that maybe instead of `thisworkbook` you should use `activeworkbook` so that it adds a sheet to whichever workbook you are using when you push your button.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the add-in workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where the code is running - in this case your add-in.

You probably need `ActiveWorkbook` here

Comment: Nice answer (at the same time as the first two comments lol).